# What's Agepoyo and Doyagao?

Tags: daily-lives-of-high-school-boys

In the last episode of *Danshi Koukousei no Nichijou*, part "High School Boys and Lies", Motoharu asks Yoshitake about different things to which Yoshitake gives absurd replies (with the exception of the last one):

> - What's "Twitter"?
> - What's "KY"?
> - What's "Tsundere"?
> - What's "Doyagao"?
> - What's "Agepoyo"?
> - What's an "MMORPG"?

An example of the absurdity of the answers:

> **Motoharu:** What is Twitter?
>
> **Yoshitake:** It's Italian food.

I understand all of them except `Doyagao` and `Agepoyo`. Tried googling but didn't get it. Can someone explain them simply?

Comment: FWIW "doyagao" is translated as "doya face" in the Hulu upload.

Comment: Googling for "doya face" gives this: http://en.rocketnews24.com/2014/01/20/the-doya-gao-phenomenon-and-where-youre-most-likely-to-see-it/ which fits in more or less with the results on Google Images when I tried searching in Japanese. Still not sure about "agepoyo".

Comment: Whoever created those subtitles was remarkably lazy.... By the way, are you sure that you know what "KY" means? In this case, it's "kuuki yomenai" (空気読めない), a term used to pejoratively describe people who miss implicit social cues. cf. http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/372/

Comment: Lol yes, I know what KY means, but thanks anyways. I asked this question last year: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/23871/what-does-k-y-mean :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Doya-gao (ドヤ顔)** is a slang term for the face made when showing off. Usually they make the recipient irked, though sometimes it is considered cute depending on the situation. It comes from the Kansai dialect version of "dou da「どうだ」", which is "do ya「どや」", a phrase that translates to "How's that?" So, the literal translation would be a "how's that face".  A Google search provides some nice [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%83%89%E3%83%A4%E9%A1%94&tbm=isch).

**Age-poyo (あげぽよ)** is a slang term used by gals (or kogals), a subculture set of high school girls. The "age" part comes from "age-age (アゲアゲ)", another slang term meaning "in high spirits" or "rockin'".  Basically these terms are used when you're liking something or things are getting exciting. The "poyo" part is an auxiliary suffix that has no meaning. Apparently it was added because it "sounded good".  Note that native Japanese speakers have trouble with understanding this, so I'm not sure if my explanation is 100% accurate. Also, I do believe that the word is dying out since its peak in 2010.